# Is there a way to make 'on.wheel' function work for smartphones?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, tablet, mousewheel

I just bring a website online (please follow this link : http://www.horstaxe.fr/) and I'm checking it on different devices. For now, its precise look is only available for 1600x900 screens with Chrome browser. I'll have a hard time to correct all media queries parameters I set (for screen sizes and for browsers compatibility), but what worries me most is that the scroll function's only working on laptops or computers, not on mobiles or tablets. I'm not able to say if it's because of a 'not Chrome browser' use or because of the function.

Here's the function I'm talking about :

```
$(window).on('wheel', function(e) {
var delta = e.originalEvent.deltaY;
if (delta > 0) $('div[id^="image"]').animate({ top: "+=15" }, 10, "easeOutCubic");
else $('div[id^="image"]').animate({ top: "-=15" }, 10, "easeOutCubic");
});
```

Can someone enlighten me ? Maybe it is needed to use a trick to call this function for 'touch screens' ?

Many thanks :) !

Comment: Oww... possible click trick trap :-)

Comment: Btw, if you a worrying about different resolutions (and perhaps zoom levels as well), you might want to try a framework like bootstrap: http://getbootstrap.com/ it will handle all the different media types for you. You only need to stick to the framework.

Comment: Hi @Stefan ! What do you mean exactly by 'click trick trap' ? Thank you very much for your advice, I'll have a further look on Bootstrap, I already heard about it but didn't really know what purpose it serves. I don't know if you had a look on my 'media queries' file (source code) but you're right, I had a lot of css to set and your method will may prevent me from adjusting some elements for each screen size. Besides, do you have any clue to allow the wheel function on touch screens ? Thanks !

Comment: @Stefan : A friend told me to have a look on that : http://hammerjs.github.io/ I'll let you know if it solves my problem !

Comment: That would be nice to hear. If you find something, you can post it as answer here, you'll score points with that :)

Comment: ps: the click trick trap refers to luring people to your site, just a silly joke